# Limit of analytical function

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Let $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of analytical functions in $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ ($U$ open), ie. $f_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_{nk}(x_0) (x-x_0)^k$ for all $x_0 \in U$ and $x \in U$ with $|x-x_0| \lt dist(x_0,\partial U)$.

Question: If $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly against a function $f \in C^0(U)$, are the sequences $(c_{nk}(x_0))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ bounded?

The answer is yes, as the $f_n$ are also analytical as functions in $\mathbb{C}$ (on a certain open set), ie. holomorphic. Therefore $f$ is holomorphic, ie. $f$ is analytic, so the sequences $(c_{nk}(x_0))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converge.

Does a more elementary proof exist?

Comment: Is "Limes" a typo?

Comment: @MatthewConroy: Changes to *limit*.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is actually no. For example, by Weierstrass there are polynomials $p_n(x) \to |x|$ uniformly on $(-1,1)$ and $|x|$ is not even differentiable at $0.$

On the point that the power series converges if $|x-x_0|< d(x,\partial U),$ that's also false. For example $f(x) = 1/(1+x^2)$ is real analytic on $\mathbb {R}$ but its power series at $0$ converges only in $(-1,1).$